# Will a game from USA run on an Xbox 360 console bought in Brazil?

Tags: xbox-360, rocksmith-2014

I have an Xbox 360 bought in Brazil and I am thinking about to buy [this version of Rocksmith](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D6PTMSW) in USA.

Will this game work in my Brazilian console?

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely, seeing as the game and console are both region locked to their original countries.

There may be some exceptions that I am unaware of, however.